# ¿Cómo descargar una imagen con R Studio?

Tags: r, imagen, rstudio

A todos:

Estoy tratando de descargar la siguiente imagen:

> (data:image/png;base64,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)

Con R Studio, pero no he tenido éxito ya que sólo obtengo este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que tengo hasta el momento:

```
link <- "data:image/png;base64,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"

z <- tempfile()

download.file(link,z, mode="W")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que tienes no es un enlace, sino una cadena cifrada en base 64 que ya sabes por la cabecera que se trata de un archivo `png`, para transformar esta cadena en un archivo deberías:

1. Extraer los datos del archivo de la cadena
2. Decifrar los datos en base 64
3. Salvar finalmente el `png`

Algo así:

```
library(base64enc)
library(png)

link <- "data:image/png;base64,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"

# Obtenemos los datos crudos, a partir de la , 
data <- strsplit(link,',')[[1]][2]

# desciframos la cadena B64
png <- base64decode(data)

# Salvamos el archivo
writePNG(readPNG(png), "file.png")
```

---

Resultado `file.png:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Patricio, muchas gracias. Si quisiera descargar la imagen en jpeg, debería primero descargar en png y después convertirla a jpeg dado que en base64 está en png? Tu respuesta realmente fue sumamente útil, te agradezco nuevamente.

Comment: Lo importante es la cabecera que dice `data:image/png;`, lo cual indicaría que los datos cifrados corresponderían a un `png`, en este caso, sí, si quiere un `jpg` deberías leer el mismo y luego usar `jpeg::writeJPEG()`

Answer (score 0):

La dirección de la imagen no tiene extensión. A `download.file()` no le queda claro que efectivamente estás tratando de descargar un archivo. El link debería terminar en *.jpg*, *.png*, por poner algunos ejemplos.